# Problems posting to Facebook Wall from iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, ios5, facebook, xamarin.ios

I have a simple app that allows people to post their new entry to their Facebook wall. I'm using the iOS facebook connect implementation, only permissions required (I believe) are "publish_stream".  It works fine for me, however, I have a tester that travels a lot and he switches in and out of airplane mode during his airline travels.  He says when he switches back out of airplane mode he's not able to post the wall.

I have the user "connect" once and I store the token which is used in the graph API call I'm using via a HTTP POST to publish to the wall.  My understanding is there is no session timeout when using publish_stream just like offline_access so I assume that once we have the token the user can always post to the wall.

Can anyone think of why the airplane mode situation may be causing a problem?  Anything sound wrong in what I'm doing?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create an app that acts like this...?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9034256/is-it-possible-to-create-an-app-that-acts-like-this)

Comment: @DMCS it does not looks like a duplicate since the application is already done and he's asking on advice about networking issues wrt airplane mode

Comment: It's the same answer, Use the app token to do publish_stream to the user who has granted offline access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use both offline_access and publish_stream and see how that works after reading:

[facebook publish_stream versus offline_access on an android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948283/facebook-publish-stream-versus-offline-access-on-an-android-app)